# Android Kotlin : MediaPlayer setOnCompletionListener is not triggered

Tags: kotlin, android-mediaplayer

When I execute and play an audio by my mediaplayer to the end,  `setOnCompletionListener`  is not triggered .

Would you please tell me what other things do I have to set ?

```
 mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            val audioBuilder = AudioAttributes.Builder()
            audioBuilder.setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            audioBuilder.setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
            audioBuilder.setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            showLoading()
            val attribute : AudioAttributes = audioBuilder.build()
            mediaPlayer!!.setAudioAttributes(attribute )
            mediaPlayer!!.setOnErrorListener { mp, what, extra ->
                mp.reset();
                Log.i("SYSTEM", "mp: ${mp}\nwhat: ${what}\nextra: $extra")
                false
            }


            mediaPlayer!!.setOnCompletionListener {
                Toast.makeText(this,"end",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }


            mediaPlayer!!.setOnPreparedListener {
                hideLoading()
                mediaPlayer!!.start()
            }
```

Comment: Did you try to play another file? Sometimes file have improper headers and method could be not called.

Comment: I have found out that the completionListener can be fetch after calling start()